# How to Integrate Webtrekk with Google Tag Manager

Tags: analytics, noscript, google-tag-manager

I am currently using Webtrekk for our analytics.

Recently, I implemented Google Tag Manager to manage and consolidate all tags. I am thinking of adding Webtrekk into Google Tag Manager and I was wondering if there are any compatibility issues.

According to http://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2787990, tags that use document.write, either in the snippet or in the linked JavaScript are not supported by Google Tag Manager. I found out that the linked Javascript (webtrekk_v3.2js) contains"document.write".

What do you suggest as a workaround for this?

Can I just use the tracking code inside the  tags instead and skip the javascript totally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"document_write" is only needed for old browsers and is not needed anymore. ask webtrekk for the newest js release and there is no "document_write" anymore.

we implemented webtrekk successful .

Answer (score 0):

In know it is late, but just in case somebody ever searches for this: Webtrekk was bought by Mapp and is called Mapp Intelligence now. There is a Google Tag ManagerTemplate called Mapp Cloud which can be used, more infos here: https://documentation.mapp.com/1.0/en/how-to-integrate-mapp-intelligence-with-google-tag-manager-7239473.html